# Anchor text is not displaying on navbar in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, bootstrap-5, nav

I have created a Navbar.js component in my React js app. The problem I am facing is that my navbar anchor text is not showing. When I remove the Bootstrap "collapse" class, the text is displayed, but the collapsing does not work properly.

**Here is my NAVBAR component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/about">Navbar</Link>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/about">About</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

[navbar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy0Ie.png)

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "personal-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be working. Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: yeah sure, I have added package.json above.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your dependencies. The wrong installation of Bootstrap could cause this bug. Try to copy this to the head of your index.html file;     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">` and check if it's working.